# about vue-cli 3.x main.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

In vue-cli 2.x, when you create a vue object in main.js,
I remember that the template option was available.

In vue-cli 3.x, however, using the template option causes an error and you must use the render function.

I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vue ui execute
project preset add/remove(project setting)
runtimeCompiler : true setting

or vue.config.js write

```
module.exports = {
runtimeCompiler: true
}
```